# How can I get Pubnub read / unread count?

Tags: javascript, angular, pubnub

1. We implemented a chat application using pubnub, but our problem is can't show unread message count?
2. How can I show read/unread status for each message?

Answer (score 3):

Give each message a unique ID, like "message1234."

When a user "sees" a message, publish a new message that says 
"lastSeen: message1234."

This way you can keep track of how far the user has read.